# Is there a library/API like Leaflet available for Starmaps?

Tags: python, javascript, r, astronomy

#### Disclaimer

I attempted to find an answer on the [Astronomy Stack Exchange site](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/51508/is-there-a-library-api-like-leaflet-available-for-starmaps), but seeing that I didn't gain much traction there, I'm posting here to see if anyone can help with my query.

#### Some Background

I am working (recreationally) on [R package](https://github.com/benyamindsmith/mapBliss) that allows for users to create custom, print quality, map art that is commonly found on many drop shipping sites. Seeing that there are sites that offer [custom star maps](https://mapsformoments.co.uk/9-star-map?step=design) I am exploring development of a suite of functions that would allow for custom star maps similar to what I've done for world maps.

#### The Question

Does there exist a library similar to [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com) (or is somehow possible with Leaflet) that allows for creation of custom star maps?